# Changing tracks in AVAudio stream

Tags: objective-c, ios7, avfoundation

I have a program that uses a segmented control to control an audio stream using the AVFoundation audio functions. However, it looks awfully messy and I have to re-instantiate it every time I want to change the music track.

How can I make this more elegant and clean? Do I really need to create a new player for every instance of playing a new track?

```
- (IBAction)musicChoice:(UISegmentedControl *)segmentedControl {
    switch(segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex)
    {
        { case 0:
            [self.player pause];

             currentMusic = arc4random_uniform(upperBound);

            NSString *soundFilePath =
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: _musicToPlay[currentMusic]
                                            ofType: @"mp3"];
            NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

            AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
            [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL
                                                   error: nil];

            self.player = newPlayer;

            [_player prepareToPlay];
            [_player setDelegate: self];

            [self.player play];
            break; }
        { case 1:
            [self.player pause];

            NSString *soundFilePath =
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Track1"
                                            ofType: @"mp3"];
            NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

            AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
            [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL
                                                   error: nil];

            self.player = newPlayer;

            [_player prepareToPlay];
            [_player setDelegate: self];

            [self.player play];
            break; }
        { case 2:
            [self.player pause];

            NSString *soundFilePath =
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Track2"
                                            ofType: @"mp3"];
            NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];

            AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer =
            [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL
                                                   error: nil];

            self.player = newPlayer;

            [_player prepareToPlay];
            [_player setDelegate: self];

            [self.player play];
            break; }
    }
}
```

Here is the NSArray that I'm using to cycle music tracks.

```
_musicToPlay = @[@"Track1",@"Track2",@"Track3",@"Track4",@"Track5"];
```

I already have music running by the time this IBAction is reached, which is why I use

```
[self.player pause];
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should also say that everything currently compiles and runs, I'm just wondering if there is a better way to do things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try messing around with an [AVQueuePlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/avfoundation/reference/avqueueplayer_class/index.html), and if you knew some streams in advance, you could mess with the playlist order to change which file will play next.

Otherwise, if you need to have even shorter downtime between streams, you could try a lower level framework such as [AudioQueue](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/musicaudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) or CoreAudio's [AudioUnits](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioUnitProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)